# Application not CDI enabled error- specific to one Websphere only

Tags: java, maven, websphere-8, java-6

I have a Java Restful application deployed and working fine on 2 different non-prod Websphere 8.5 and works fine. However in Prod Websphere 8.5, it fails to load and gives a 404 everytime with this error:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: The service.war module in the service-ear-prod.com application is not CDI enabled. The CDI BeanManager is not available for applications that are not CDI enabled.
```

Although I use Jersey from the application and have the Parent_LAST as class-loading policy I still get this error. The other two domains work fine.
 I use JAX-RS so not sure if I even need the application to be CDI enabled.

Upon my research on the web I found that have to include beans.xml in the WEB-INF[1] folder of the WAR but I want to be a bit cautious before trying in Prod domain.
[1]https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=986afce3-d94d-43ba-8bdd-31547bfb0c77

Here are my maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency><!-- new for 8.5 PROD -->
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
          <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: full ffdc stacktrace is here http://pastebin.ca/3684914

Comment: *UPDATE* I don't use CDI Injection. But the Websphere keeps complaining about this even though I just use JAX-RS/Jersey. 
  `The service.war module in the service-ear-Prod.com application is not CDI enabled. The CDI BeanManager is not available for applications that are not CDI enabled.`   
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi!  To follow up: What exact product level and edition is running?  Is there a stack that goes with that error message (it might be in logs, if it doesn't show with the 404 response)?  Are there either a beans.xml or any CDI annotations in the web module?